# java.lang.NullPointerException at org.primefaces.util.ResourceUtils.getComponentResources

Tags: jsf, primefaces, nullpointerexception, resources

I'm using PF6.0 and Wildfly 10 and my web app in some point needs to build some quite big grid of p:inplace objects on single page. Sounds easy.

The problem: when my grid is too big any ajax request ends with error.

To reproduce this problem I have working example:

The page test.xhtml:

```html
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
                xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
                xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
    <h:head>
        <title>Test</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h:form>
            <!--it's a part of something bigger so this part is in outputPanel-->
            <p:outputPanel id="details">
                <h:outputText value="Size: #{backBean.size}" />
            <p:panelGrid>
                <!--btw. why it forces me to set all of this variables at p.repeat?--> 
                <p:repeat value="#{backBean.content}"
                          var="_row"
                          offset="0"
                          step="1"
                          size="#{backBean.content.size()}"
                          varStatus="_rowStatus" >
                    <p:row>
                    <p:repeat value="#{_row}" 
                              var="_cell" 
                              offset="0"
                              step="1"
                              size="#{_row.size()}"
                              varStatus="_rowStatus" >
                        <p:column>
                            <p:inplace editor="true">
                                <f:facet name="output">
                                        <h:outputText value="#{_cell.output}" />                                 
                                </f:facet>
                                <f:facet name="input">
                                    <!--in real example it will be more complex with checkboxes, selectonemenu etc-->
                                    <h:outputText value="First:" />
                                    <p:inputText value="#{_cell.something}" />
                                    <br />
                                    <h:outputText value="Second:" />
                                    <p:inputText value="#{_cell.another}" />
                                </f:facet>
                            </p:inplace>
                        </p:column>
                    </p:repeat>
                    </p:row>
                </p:repeat>
            </p:panelGrid>
            

        </p:outputPanel>
            <p:commandButton value="more" update="details" actionListener="#{backBean.weNeedMore}" />
        </h:form>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

Backing bean:

```
package com.test;

import javax.inject.Named;
import javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;


@Named(value = "backBean")
@SessionScoped
public class BackBean implements Serializable {

private List<List<CellContent>> content;
private int size;

/**
 * Creates a new instance of BackBean
 */
public BackBean() {
}

private void build() {
    content = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++) {
        List<CellContent> row = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int j=0;j<size;j++) {
            CellContent cell = new CellContent();
            row.add(cell);
        }
        content.add(row);
    }    
}

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    size = 10;  

    //create first content
    build();
}

public void weNeedMore() {
    //increase until we get error after click.
    size = size + 10;
    build();
}

//plain getters & setters

public List<List<CellContent>> getContent() {
    return content;
}

public void setContent(List<List<CellContent>> content) {
    this.content = content;
}

public int getSize() {
    return size;
}

public void setSize(int size) {
    this.size = size;
}



}
```

and one class that holds my objects:

```
package com.test;


public class CellContent {

private String something = "";
private String another = "";
private String output = "click_me";

public CellContent() {
}

//some dummy update based on inputs
private void update() {
    if(!something.equals(""))
        output = something;
    if(!another.equals(""))
        output = "another: " + another;
}

//those two setters update the object
public void setSomething(String something) {
    this.something = something;
    update();
}

public void setAnother(String another) {
    this.another = another;
    update();
}

//rest are plain get&seters
public String getSomething() {
    return something;
}

public String getAnother() {
    return another;
}

public String getOutput() {
    return output;
}

public void setOutput(String output) {
    this.output = output;
}


}
```

When grid of my objects are "small" like 10x10 or 20x20 it works - I can click and update any cell.

But increasing size up to 30 (by hitting more button) leads to this error when I click anything:

> 09:47:13,602 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-89) UT005023: Exception handling request to /myapp/test.xhtml: javax.servlet.ServletException
>       at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:671)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:129)
>       at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:100)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
>       at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
>       at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
>       at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
>       at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationConstraintHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationConstraintHandler.java:51)
>       at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityConstraintHandler.java:56)
>       at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
>       at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
>       at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
>       at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
>       at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
>       at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
>       at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:284)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:263)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:174)
>       at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:202)
>       at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:793)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at org.primefaces.util.ResourceUtils.getComponentResources(ResourceUtils.java:66)
>       at org.primefaces.context.PrimePartialResponseWriter.startMetadataIfNecessary(PrimePartialResponseWriter.java:280)
>       at org.primefaces.context.PrimePartialResponseWriter.startError(PrimePartialResponseWriter.java:107)
>       at com.sun.faces.context.AjaxExceptionHandlerImpl.handlePartialResponseError(AjaxExceptionHandlerImpl.java:203)
>       at com.sun.faces.context.AjaxExceptionHandlerImpl.handle(AjaxExceptionHandlerImpl.java:127)
>       at javax.faces.context.ExceptionHandlerWrapper.handle(ExceptionHandlerWrapper.java:100)
>       at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:119)
>       at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.doPhase(RestoreViewPhase.java:123)
>       at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
>       at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:658)
>       ... 34 more

Any idea what's happen? Is there any parameter I could adjust to avoid this error? Or any other solution (my current workaround is using datagrid with pagination).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FOUND IT ;)

I switched back to PF 5.3 to check if it's PrimeFaces issue.
There is no p:repeat @ PF5.3 so I switched to ui:repeat.

Same was here but error message finally tells what's going on:

> 10:37:58,508 SEVERE [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.context] (default task-44) java.lang.IllegalStateException: UT000047: The number of parameters exceeded the maximum of 1000
>       at io.undertow.server.handlers.form.FormData.add(FormData.java:78)
>       at io.undertow.server.handlers.form.FormData.add(FormData.java:68)

All what I need to do is update max-parameters value at http-listener in standalone configuration:

```html
 <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:undertow:3.0">
            <buffer-cache name="default"/>
            <server name="default-server">
                <http-listener name="default" max-parameters="10000" socket-binding="http" redirect-socket="https"/>
```

(found it at https://developer.jboss.org/thread/241526)

Comment: Better use `partialSubmit`. This is insane.

Comment: @BalusC how to use `partialSubmit` in this specific example - when inplace is used?

Comment: Next thing with this solution is that you ask a question why the performance is bad. Better do what BalusC suggests

Comment: This is only an example, proof of concept to reproduce an error. Real world application is more complicated than that. I need to create dynamic table (I don't know how many columns, how many rows it will have at design time - it is fetched from DB). I need to build it and allow user to apply something into each cell (editor). Performance is not a problem since it will be used in intranet only and only by few users.

Comment: Love downvoters like here. Does it tell where the problem was? Yes. Does it solve the issue? Yes. Is it best piece of code in univere? Probably not, but it's not the reason for downvoting. So for future readers: this solution works in this particular problem despite any downvotes :P